# A program which creates emails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble creating a program which takes a list of first names and a list of last names, appends the two lists and adding @abc.mail.com
I haven't touched python in months so I don't even know what to do anymore. I tried creating lists and dictionaries but I don't know if it's even possible to input more than one string at a time.
To summarize:
I want a program that asks for a user to input a list for firstName, a list for lastName and then the program to append it together to make firstName.lastName@abc.mail.com
I appreciate any help that you give.

Comment: This question is at least three questions in one: get user input, get it in list form, concatenate strings to get the email address. You'll get better answers if you come here with a specific problem and some code to show how far you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def fill_list(l, promt):
    while True:
        x = input(promt)
        if not x:
            break

        l.append(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_names = list()
    last_names = list()

    fill_list(first_names, "Input first name: ")
    print('first_names: {}'.format(first_names))

    fill_list(last_names, "Input last name: ")
    print('last_names: {}'.format(last_names))

    for first, last in zip(first_names, last_names):
        print('{}.{}@abc.mail.com'.format(first, last))
```

Output:

```
Input first name: fff
Input first name: ddd
Input first name: ggg
Input first name: 
first_names: ['fff', 'ddd', 'ggg']
Input last name: 111
Input last name: 222
Input last name: 333
Input last name: 
last_names: ['111', '222', '333']
fff.111@abc.mail.com
ddd.222@abc.mail.com
ggg.333@abc.mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a very simple solution minus any fancy methods or comprehensions. 
You seem to be a Python beginner.

Try :

```
fnames = []
lnames = []

#specify a size - depends on how many names you want; ideally first and last names would match right?
len_fnames = 3
len_lnames = 3

#input loop for first names
while len(fnames) < len_fnames:
    f = raw_input('Enter a first name')
    fnames.append(f)

print fnames

#input loop for last names - you can run this once to get both first and last names
while len(lnames) < len_lnames:
    l = raw_input('Enter a last name')
    lnames.append(l)

print lnames    
#a list of the generated email IDs
email = []
for i, f in enumerate(fnames):
    email.append(f + "." +lnames[i] + "@abc.mail.com")

print email
```

See Martin's solution below - it's far more elegant and the right way to do it.